# UBB Replace username

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace {username} with the user name.

I've tried:

```
$username = htmlentities($gegevens['gebruikersnaam']);
$text = preg_replace("{username}",$username, $text);
```

But that didn't output the username.

My full code is this:

*I am only including the **bold** ubb replacer, there's a full list of things to replace so I'm leaving that out.*

```
function ubbreplace($text){
    $text = preg_replace("#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#si","<strong>\\1</strong>", $text);
    $text = nl2br($text);
    return $text;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep it simple and use `str_replace` instead

```
$username = htmlentities($gegevens['gebruikersnaam']);
$text = str_replace('{username}',$username, $text);
```

Comment: Tried that but still outputs {username} instead of the actual username. How would I be able to use your code with preg_replace?

Comment: @BobbyJ. Then show us what `var_dump($text);` gives you

Comment: @Rizier123 Nothing really, it doesn't give me any errors or anything. I have error reporting on.

Comment: @BobbyJ. How does your text looks like.

Comment: @Rizier123 It looks like how RiggsFolly gave it to me. I'm using str_replace.

Comment: No they mean do an `echo $text` and show us what is in that variable